# Using Trim method how to remove space/enter in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, trim

```html
 processSearch() {
        this.search.trim().length>0;
        // this.searchHistory.push(this.search);
        this.search = ''; 
      },
```

```js
preventLeadingSpace(e) {
        // only prevent the keypress if the value is blank
        if (!e.target.value) e.preventDefault();
        // otherwise, if the leading character is a space, remove all leading white-space
        else if (e.target.value[0]==' ') e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/^\s*/, "");
      },
```

```html
 <input
          
          id="SearchText"
          type="text"
          v-model="search"
          @keydown.enter="enter"
          @click="onClick"
          @keyup.enter="processSearch"
          @input="change"
          @keyup="inputChanged"
          @keydown.down="onArrow"
          @keydown.up="onArrow"
          @keydown.space="preventLeadingSpace"
         
        />


<ul class="list-inline" >
    
      <li
        class="list-inline-item list-group-item-primary"
        v-for="(item, index) in searchHistory
          .slice(-5)
          .reverse()
          .map((s) => s.trim())"
        :key="index"
        @click="selectPreviousSearch(index)"
      >
        {{ item }}
      </li>

    </ul>
```

```html
this.search.trim().length>0

// tried using this to stop enter, But doesn't work.
```

I am trying to do the search functionality ,If user enter anything in the search, result will be displayed in li. Now the issue is, even without entering any data simply if i click on enter key from  the keyboard, then also it is showing as result in li.

Second issue is, If is click on input, dropdown is displaying. But when i click outside of input dropdown is not closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the white spaces, or to trim the input, `Vue` come up with such functionality. You can use `v-model.trim`  try this:

```
<form @submit.prevent="processSearch">
<input
          id="SearchText"
          type="text"
          v-model.trim="search"
          @keydown.enter="enter"
          @click="onClick"
          @input="change"
          @keyup="inputChanged"
          @keydown.down="onArrow"
          @keydown.up="onArrow"
          @keydown.space="preventLeadingSpace"
         
        />
</form>
```

Then your `processSearch` function:

```
processSearch() {
       if(this.search){
            this.searchHistory.push(this.search); this.search = '';
         } 
 }
```

Comment: Tried this  but same issue, Is there any regex for not accepting enter keyword

Comment: I am using regex  /^\s*/, ""  For this regex can i add, not accepting enter keyword

Comment: I don't get what you are saying? please rephrase your question

Comment: Present issue is, In the Input field without entering any data if i click enter, it is proceeding

Comment: `@keyup.enter="processSearch" ` this lines tells vue that run processSearch when i click the enter key when the input has focus. If you don't want the enter key to work then, remove that line from your code

Comment: I have updated my processSearch method, From there i have removed this.searchHistory.push(this.search);

Comment: After removing that line, it's working now. But after entering data it's not showing now,

can i give condition like if data only proceed else do not proceed(i.e, if its blank or with spaces ,without entering data)

Comment: i don't understand what you are saying, please share the code

Comment: Sorry, This is my code  processSearch() {
        this.search.trim().length>0;
        // this.searchHistory.push(this.search);
        this.search = ''; 
      },

Comment: let me edit the code and to perform what you have asked for.

Comment: Thanks it's working, But accepting duplicate values

Comment: What do you mean it's accepting duplicates?

Comment: For example if i enter "hi" in input field, and press enter data reflecting in li, For the second time if i enter same "hi" and press enter (then it is displaying two times "hi" "hi"

Comment: Then, you should do that yourself, your question was on handling input  not handling duplicate values. show me the code you tried to implement the duplicate, then i will help you from there, please vote for the answer that i helped you with

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you on how to avoid duplicates on your `<li>` items

```
.... 
data(){
    return{
    items: [], 
    search: "" 
} 
}, methods:{
processSearch() {
       if(this.search){
            this.searchHistory.push(this.search); this.search = '';
           if(this.items.indexOf(this.search) === -1){
        this.items.push(this.search)
        } 
         } 
 } 
}
....
```

Now on your lists

```
<ul class="list-inline"  >
    
      <li
        class="list-inline-item list-group-item-primary"
        v-for="(item, index) in items
          .slice(-5)
          .reverse()
          .map((s) => s.trim())"
        :key="index"
       ..... 
      >
        {{ item }}
      </li>

    </ul>
```